# Avoiding getting cached content from raw.githubusercontent.com

Tags: github

I noticed that when using curl to get content from github using this format:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${org}/${repo}/${branch}/path/to/file
```

It will sometimes return cached/stale content.  For example with this sequence of operations:

1. curl [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${org}/${repo}/${branch}/path/to/file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/$%7Borg%7D/$%7Brepo%7D/$%7Bbranch%7D/path/to/file)
2. Push a new commit to that branch
3. curl [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${org}/${repo}/${branch}/path/to/file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/$%7Borg%7D/$%7Brepo%7D/$%7Bbranch%7D/path/to/file)

Step 3 will return the same content as step 1 and not reflect the new commit.

How can avoid getting a stale version?

I noticed on the Github WebUI, it adds a token to the url, eg:  `?token=AABCIPALAGOZX5R` which presumably avoids getting cached content.  What's the nature of this token and how can I emulate this?  Would tacking on `?token=$(date +%s)` work?

Also I'm looking for a way to avoid the stale content without having to switch to a commit hash in the url, since it will require more changes.  However, if that's the only way to achieve it, then I'll go that route.

Answer (score 5):

`?token=$(date +%s)` worked for me :)

Comment: That won't work for private repositories, and since usually GitHub rejects access even to public repositories with invalid credentials, it may break at any time.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub caches this data because otherwise frequently requested files would involve serving a request to the backend service each time and this is more expensive than serving a cached copy.  Using a CDN provides improved performance and speed.  You cannot bypass it.

The token you're seeing in the URL is a temporary token that is issued for the logged-in user.  You cannot use a random token, since that won't pass authentication.

If you need the version of that file in a specific commit, then you'll need to explicitly specify that commit.  However, do be aware that you should not do this with some sort of large-scale automated process as a way to bypass caching.  For example, you should not try to do this to always get the latest version of a file for the purposes of a program you're distributing or multiple instances of a service you're running.  You should provide that data yourself, using a CDN if necessary.  That way, you can decide for yourself when the cache needs to be expired and get both good performance and the very latest data.

If you run such a process anyway, you may cause an outage or overload, and your repository or account may be suspended or blocked.